# jQuery Slider - Moving Sliders at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I have three sliders as follows:-

```
<div class="slider" data-min="3800" data-max="30000" data-value="3848" data-step="500" data-target=".calc-deposit"></div>
<div class="slider" data-min="15400" data-max="120000" data-value="15393" data-step="2000" data-target=".calc-loan"></div> 
<div class="slider" data-min="57000" data-max="450000" data-value="57724" data-step="7500" data-target=".calc-mortgage"></div> 


$('.slider').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.slider({
        range: "max",
        min: $el.data('min'),
        max: $el.data('max'),
        value: $el.data('value'),
        step: $el.data('step'),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $($el.data('target')).html('£' + ui.value);

            // place code here which will execute when *any* slider moves
        }
    });
});
```

What I want to do is regardless of which slider you use, they all increase at the same time.

All three sliders have different increments so they need to update accordingly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[Example](http://www.persimmonhomes.com/help-to-buy)

Comment: if you are concerned about the increments, why are the initial values not in the increment? ie `3848` is not a 500 increment between `3800` and `30000`?

Comment: Since they have different steps/values you should have a rule which you have to follow. What kind of rule do you have, let say if the 1st slider it is on 4300, what about other 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using the `stop` and `change` event:-

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.slider({
    range: "max",
    min: $el.data('min'),
    max: $el.data('max'),
    value: $el.data('value'),
    step: $el.data('step'),
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var percent = (100 / ($(this).data('max') - $(this).data('min'))) * $(this).slider('value');
      $('.slider').not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).slider('value', (($(this).data('max') - $(this).data('min')) / 100) * percent);
      });
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $($el.data('target')).html('£' + ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6b777tL8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Based on BG101's answer, this is the final result:-

```
jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
    var $el = jQuery(this);
    $el.slider({
        range: "max",
        min: $el.data('min'),
        max: $el.data('max'),
        value: $el.data('value'),
        step: $el.data('step'),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var percent = (100 / (jQuery(this).data('max') - jQuery(this).data('min'))) * jQuery(this).slider('value');

            jQuery('.slider').not(this).each(function() {
                jQuery(this).slider(
                    'value', 
                    ((jQuery(this).data('max') - jQuery(this).data('min')) / 100) * percent
                );
            });
            jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
                var thisTarget = jQuery(this).data('target');
                var thisValue = jQuery(this).slider('option','value');

                jQuery(thisTarget+' span').html(thisValue);
            });

        },
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/08u3w3hg/)

(just thought I'd share)